# How to test triggered events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, testing, jasmine

Why does this test not pass?

```
beforeEach(function(){
    loadFixtures('addvehicle.html');
});

it ("should trigger change event on #selectLanguage", function(){
    spyOnEvent('#selectLanguage', 'change');
    $('#selectLanguage').trigger('change');
    expect('change').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('#selectLanguage');
});
```

My fixture file looks like this:

```
<div id="selectTypeWrapper"></div>
<select id="selectLanguage"></select>
```

I get this error:

> Error: Expected event [object Object] to have been triggered on
>   #selectLanguage

Do I have to set a change listener before? (how would this work?)

Comment: pls post your html from `addvehicle.html`

Comment: there are two ways to set a change listener: 1. you could try to add `onChange="function(){}"` to the `#selectLanguage` html tag. 2. add `$('#selectLanguage).on('change', function() {});` as second line in `beforeEach`.

Comment: the addvehicle.html is the two lines `<div id="selectTypeWrapper"></div>
<select id="selectLanguage"></select>`

Comment: your first way to add a listener does not work. the second one works, but it does not solve my problem...

Comment: hmm... i never used event spies, but you could try this: `var changeSpy = spyOnEvent('#selectLanguage', 'change'); $('#selectLanguage').trigger('change'); expect(changeSpy).toHaveBeenTriggered();`. [See here for more information](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/js-ref/testing-dom-events-using-jquery-and-jasmine-2.0.html)

Comment: My first solution didn't work, because it should be `onchange` instead of `onChange`.

Comment: i used the website in your link for orientation. but it does not work for me...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your code does not work, but maybe you could try this:

```
var changeSpy;

beforeEach(function(){
    loadFixtures('addvehicle.html');
    changeSpy = jasmine.createSpy('handleChange() spy');
    $('#selectLanguage').change(changeSpy);
});

it ("should trigger change event on #selectLanguage", function(){
    $('#selectLanguage').change();
    expect(changeSpy).toBeDefined();
    expect(changeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

It will test the event indirectly.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. unfortunately i write this code for my thesis and I have to use the original syntax...

Comment: what "original syntax" do you mean?

Comment: i have to use for example .toHaveBeenTriggered() and other things from jasmine-jquery

Comment: Oh okay. Unfortunatly i can't help you with that, because i never used it before... but good luck :D